# Is there a way to track which element was clicked using GWT?

Tags: java, html, gwt

I am new in GWT world, previously I was working with JavaScript. I have some web-page where are multiple element. And I need to track which element was clicked using GWT.

I am using GWT 2.8.1

```html
<div class="FileRow">
  <a href="http://l24-n52:/admin/downloadresource=f&amp;table=R_Document&amp;id=405&amp;filename=1000x700.jpg" target="blank" class="fileLink jpg" tabindex="1" id="jpg1"></a>
</div>
<div class="FileRow">
  <a href="http://l24-  n52:/admin/downloadresource=f&amp;table=R_Document&amp;id=405&amp;filename=1000x700.jpg" target="blank" class="fileLink jpg" tabindex="2" id="jpg2"></a>
</div>
<div class="FileRow">
  <a href="http://l24-  n52:/admin/downloadresource=f&amp;table=R_Document&amp;id=405&amp;filename=1000x700.jpg" target="blank" class="fileLink pdf" tabindex="3" id="pdf"></a>
</div>

GWT realization

    Integer tabIndex = 1, count = 1;
    
    for (final FieldFileInfo info : clientData.getFileInfo()) {
     final FlowPanel rowPanel = new FlowPanel();
     rowPanel.setStyleName("FileRow");
       
     final HyperlinkPanel fileLink = FileInfoParser.getLinkPanel(info);
     fileLink.setStyleName("fileLink");
     fileLink.setTabIndex(tabIndex++);
     fileLink.setText("");
    switch (info.getFileExtension()) {
     case "png" :
      fileLink.addStyleName("png");
         fileLink.getElement().setId("png");
      break;
        case "jpg" :
      fileLink.addStyleName("jpg");
      fileLink.getElement().setId("jpg"+count);
      break;
        case "pdf" :
      fileLink.addStyleName("pdf");
      fileLink.getElement().setId("pdf");
      break;
        default :
      fileLink.addStyleName("file");
      fileLink.getElement().setId("file");
    }

rowPanel.add(fileLink);
count++;

}

click realization

Element openPng = Document.get().getElementById("png"); 
  Event.sinkEvents(openPng, Event.ONCLICK); 
  Event.setEventListener(openPng, new OpenModalHandler());
```

Now my click realization works only on first element with required ID. However in future there might be several elements with the same id and as a result I could not alert another elements.

Expected result is when I click on first element, GWT using Window.alert() show which element was clicked.

Comment: Can you also share how you use this html in your gwt application?

Comment: And how you've added the ClickHandler already? Chances are what you already have will work, just needs a small tweak.

Comment: I have added GWT realization code. Now it looks like something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is really simple.
To track which element was clicked I just modified case with:

```
fileLink.addClickHandler(new ClickHandlerData<Integer>(tabIndex) {
                        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                            Window.alert("You clicked on " getData());
                        }
});
```

Also implement new class with ClickHandlerData

```
public abstract class ClickHandlerData<I> implements ClickHandler {
  private I data;

  public ClickHandlerData(I data) {
      this.data = data;
  }

  public I getData() {
      return data;
  }

  public void setData(I data) {
      this.data = data;
  }
}
```